# Undeleteable/ invisible .txt file

Tags: c#, file, text, protected, invisible

Currently I create a GUID-key in C#, to place it on a USB flash drive. I use this key for user identification. The key itself is inside a .txt-file, which is easy to manipulate. Is there a way to make the .txt-file undeleteable and invisible but still readable?

Comment: *undeleteable and invisible* by whom? First noobie or experimented hackers?

Comment: Better use some kind of encryption

Comment: I think it will be almost impossible to make it undeleteable and invisible for experimented hackers. So average users shouldn´t be able to manipulate it.

Comment: _"invisible but still readable"_ you 
notice the contradiction yourself?

Comment: It should be readable for my application, not for user.

Comment: Bad idea. I recall in past there was a possibility to write hidden info on outer sectors (not used by FAT) of floppy disk, but this was possible because technology wasn't perfect. USB stick doesn't contains anything like this. What you can try to do is to store information into a normal file but: 1) encrypt it 2) bound it (not sure if there is a way to get USB drive-specific and unique enough information). First will ensure what nobody can use information. Second - what it can't be copied (e.g.: it will not work with another USB stick). This should be secure enough.

Comment: After searching a little more, I found out that every USB device has some attributes that are looking like GUIDs (Device Path, Container ID, Volume). Does anyone know if one of them is permanent? In that case I wouldn´t have to create an own GUID key in a text-file.

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of license for your software? No way this could keep an hacker away

Comment: No, I just want to create a user authentification. For that I need a unique key that is located on a USB flash drive. Security is not the major issue, I just need that for a project that should show different methods of user autenthification. One of them should be via USB. Isn´t there any id or something like that, that identifis a flash drive uniquely?

Comment: Sorry but I would say that in this context (user identification) security IS _a major issue_

Comment: Yes of course in general that´s right. But it´s a project, I´m studing. If that project shows that there is no way to do user authentification via USB, that is 100% safe, it is also fine. Then the project has shown that this isn´t possible. But it would be nice if I had a method to show how it could be done and to explain where the security problems are. So I think, I will do the "hide the .txt-file"-method, if there isn´t a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Imagine what would happen if this *were* possible. Yeah.

Make the file hidden - maybe hidden+system. That's the best you can do. If the user deletes this anyway, well, that's his problem. You did the contractual "hiding", and you can't be responsible for the actions of a user who knowingly overcomes those safety precautions.

Comment: *Imagine what would happen if this were possible* Universe will implode :p

Comment: Would be a lot of fun if you could programmatically fill a hard drive with files that are not to be seen

Answer (score 1):

The best you can probably do is to hide the file. You would do that like this

```
string path = "";
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: Yes that is what I searched for, after I was reading Luaans answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting file permissions as **Deny** - *Delete*, *Change Permissions* and *Take Ownership* and **Allow** - *Read Permissions*

***Programatically,*** you can do it by using [File.SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically, what you are doing progmatically is:

Going to `File > Properties > Security Tab > Advanced > Permission Tab > Change Permission > Add User > Setting Permissions.`

*File Properties*

[image: File Properties]

*Advanced Permissions*

[image: Permissions]

*Add User*

[image: Users]

*Set Permissions*

[image: SetPermissions]

Comment: Note that ACL is only available on NTFS, and it doesn't help you if you run under the same user.